# When I try and use Playsound() in c the compiler doesn't even compile it

Tags: c

So I've been trying to use this function called Playsound() but it just throws an error. the error is C:\Users\ETHANZ~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ctmDDBF.tmp:C:\Users\ETHANZ~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ctmDCC3.tmp:(.text+0xd): undefined reference to `PlaySoundA@12'

also here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main() {
    PlaySound("intro.mp3", NULL, SND_ASYNC);
}
```

Comment: Add `-lwinmm` to the linker flags.

Comment: what are linker flags?

Comment: Do you compile directly from the console, or from an IDE (if yes, which one)?

Comment: how did you compile it? if you did something like ```gcc test.cpp -o test.exe``` it won't work. As HolyBlackCat told, you have to use linker flags to compile it.

Comment: oh, ok. I guess i would have to use a different compiler. any recomendations?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MSVC as your compiler you can use a [library pragma](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/comment-c-cpp?view=msvc-160) in your source.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "winmm")

int main()
{
    PlaySound("intro.mp3", NULL, SND_ASYNC);
}
```